# exec line from file in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read commands from a text file and execute each line from a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line;    do 
     $line
done < "commands.txt"
```

In some cases, if `$line` contains commands that are meant to run in background, eg `command 2>&1 &` they will not start in background, and will run in the current script context.

Any ideea why?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do "source commands.txt" instead of writing your own loop?

Comment: what does "source" do? I'm trying to test it now

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). And then use `source` (or `.`) as Jim Lewis suggests. `source` does pretty much what the first sentence in your question says.

Comment: can you please post this as an answer? unless i get an explanation why may way didn't work, this seems to do the trick

Comment: source has the same effect as pasting the content of the specified file in your script at the location of the source command.  IOW, it's doing exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if all your commands are inside "commands.txt", essentially, you can call it a shell script. That's why you can either source it, or run it like normal, ie chmod u+x , then you can execute it using `sh commands.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I don't have anything to add to ghostdog74's answer about the right way to do this, but I can cover why it's failing: The shell parses I/O redirections, backgrounding, and a bunch of other things before it does variable expansion, so by the time `$line` is replaced by `command 2>&1 &` it's too late to recognize `2>&1` and `&` as anything other than parameters to `command`.

You could improve this by using `eval "$line"` but even there you'll run into problems with multiline commands (e.g. while loops, if blocks, etc).  The `source` and `sh` approaches don't have this problem.